Apache Mina SFTP server only returning 8192 bytes on download
We have a mock SFTP server that creates and serves files in a local file system. It was originally written using the jcraft sftp library, then was converted over to Apache Mina with the release of Spring Boot 3.
If using sshd-core and sshd-sftp 2.7.0, it is capable of returning “large” files (over 8192 bytes) to sftp clients. However, if I use more recent versions of the libraries, it will only return the first 8192 bytes of the file. It also looks like an eof byte is returned (with a second call to the read function in our SftpEventListener) in the former case.
I’ve looked around and can’t find a setting that would resolve this. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.
I’ve tried editing buffer sizes and other properties and using different version of the libraries. As mentioned previously it works with ssh-core/sftp 2.7.0 but not later version.
